# Can't install some driver modules from C program

Tags: c, linux, module, embedded-linux, drivers

I have an embedded Linux application that can find and install *some* drivers from my C based application, but there are other drivers that it can't find at all.

From application:

```
system("insmod i2c_core.ko");
```

Debug error message:

```
insmod: i2c_core.ko: no module by that name found
```

However I have no problem installing any of the same drivers from the command line using the insmod command.

It's not a driver sequence dependency problem because the error message would be different than the above error message.

Linux version is 2.6.10 (old yes, but from reference design)

All the drivers are under this path '/lib/modules' and are built as part of the kernel build.

Comment: Try using an absolute path. Also, `system`? Do you really need to run a shell?

Comment: What is the difference between the drivers you *can* install and these you *cannot*? Path? Permissions?

Comment: Could it be that your /lib/modules/i2c_core.ko is actually a symlink to a missing file? Check with $ ls -l /lib/modules

Comment: Yes I could try an absolute path but I don't like to hard code paths. Besides it's a work around. I'd really like to know why some drivers are found and others aren't.

Comment: Permissions are the same. The error says the file is not found...doesn't say permission problem.

Comment: Path 1 (works): kernel/drivers/video/avalanche_glcd

Comment: Path 2 (doesn't work): /kernel/drivers/i2c

Comment: i2c-core.ko is not a symlink.

Comment: There are some fairly apparent security hazards to this approach, as your app presumably needs to run as root to achieve this (or at least be able to `setUID()` to `root`.  A better approach might be  to execute a script with the setUID permission.

Answer (score 0):

`insmod` wants the correct path (absolute or relative, `insmod i2c_core.ko` is same as `insmod ./i2c_core.ko`). If the module is properly installed for the kernel, try using `modprobe`:

```
system("modprobe i2c_core");
```

Otherwise, you need to figure out how to find the correct path to the module file.

Comment: Why doesn't it need the path for other drivers that do install?

Comment: Modprobe doesn't work. Module dependency files are not generated.

Comment: Have you run `depmod -a` after building new modules? Also, double-check current working directory (both when you test from command line and when you try to load from your application). Anyway, at least my `insmod` on Ubuntu does not find modules without path (and `man insmod` does not talk anything about search path).

Comment: Yes just looking into depmod -a.

Comment: Sorry what exactly do you mean double check? Double check for what?

Comment: I do insmod from the same directory as I run the program from. That what you mean?

Comment: @carlh Yeah, basically that (unless the program changes working directory before executing `insmod`).

Comment: depmod -a -b /home/carl/SandBox/PhoneDev/SourceCode/buildroot/build_mipsel_nofpu/root -r 2.6.10_dev-malta-mips2_fp_len

Comment: The dependency file shows all appropriate dependencies:

Comment: modprobe fails to find drivers

Comment: # modprobe avalanche_ssp_i2c.ko
modprobe: module avalanche_ssp_i2c.ko not found.
modprobe: failed to load module avalanche_ssp_i2c.ko